# Getting name of element type doesn't work in Iron python for Revit

Tags: python, ironpython, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I am working in Iron python in pyRevit environment and my code is as follows:

```
element_types = \
        DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc)\
          .OfCategory(DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)\
          .WhereElementIsElementType()\ # getting family types not elements
          .ToElements()

for ele in element_types:
    print(ele.Name)
```

As per Revit API documentation this should work and probably works in C#. There `ele.Name` works both as setter and getter.
But in Ironpython above code fails, returning an `AttributeError: Name`. But when i try `ele.Name = "new_family_type_name"` it works fine.

So my question is how to make `ele.Name` work to get the family type name.

Comment: Yup there is a bug. Try `DB.Element.Name.GetValue(ele)`

Comment: Its returning `AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'GetValue'`. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normally one of the earliest quirks that you come across with RPS - but not to worry, its an easy fix. Try:

```
for ele in element_Types:
     print Element.Name.__get__(ele)
```

Comment: I was looking for this for long time.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
from rpw import db

collector = db.Collector(of_class='WallType')
element_types = collector.get_elements()    

for ele in element_types:
    print(ele.name)
```